# cookbook not found on chef server

Tags: automation, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am trying to upload cookbook on chef server I am using elasticsearch and written my wrapper cookbook my-elasticsearch
 but I am getting following error :

```
iMac:chef-repo abc$ knife cookbook upload elasticsearch --cookbook-path cookbooks/
Uploading elasticsearch  [0.3.13]
Uploaded 1 cookbook.
iMac:chef-repo abc$ knife cookbook upload my-elasticsearch
Uploading magnetic-elk   [0.1.0]
ERROR: Cookbook my-elasticsearch depends on cookbook elasticsearch=0.3.13 version >= 0.0.0,
ERROR: which is not currently being uploaded and cannot be found on the server.
iMac:chef-repo abc$
```

I checked chef server and elasticsearch  [0.3.13] is present on chef server.

This is in

site-cookbooks/my-elasticsearch/metadata.rb

```
depends 'elasticsearch' '= 0.3.13'
depends 'simple-kibana' '= 0.1.1'
```

Anyone know what I am missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your `metadata.rb`. It looks like it uses `elasticsearch=0.3.13` as cookbook name (while saying `version >= 0.0.0`). So you likely have a syntax error there when specifying the version. Make sure you have `depends "elasticsearch", "= 0.3.13"`

Answer (score 0):

Following changes solved the issue.

depends 'elasticsearch', '= 0.3.13'
depends 'simple-kibana', '= 0.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are missing the commas in your `depends` statement.  As a result, chef is looking for a cookbook named `elasticsearch=0.3.13` with a version of `>=0.0.0`, rather than a cookbook named `elasticsearch` with a version of `=0.3.13`